# Question about strpos: how to get 2nd occurrence of a string?

Tags: php, string

I understand that this function will get the first occurrence of the string.

But what I want is the 2nd occurrence.

How to go about doing that?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492759/find-the-second-occurrence-of-a-char-in-a-string-php

Answer (score 62):

I know this question is kind of old, but here's a function I wrote to get the Xth occurrence of a substring, which may be helpful for other people that have this issue and stumble over this thread.

```
/**
 * Find the position of the Xth occurrence of a substring in a string
 * @param $haystack
 * @param $needle
 * @param $number integer > 0
 * @return int
 */
function strposX($haystack, $needle, $number) {
    if ($number == 1) {
        return strpos($haystack, $needle);
    } elseif ($number > 1) {
        return strpos($haystack, $needle, strposX($haystack, $needle, $number - 1) + strlen($needle));
    } else {
        return error_log('Error: Value for parameter $number is out of range');
    }
}
```

Or a simplified version:

```
function strposX($haystack, $needle, $number = 0)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle,
        $number > 1 ?
        strposX($haystack, $needle, $number - 1) + strlen($needle) : 0
    );
}
```

Comment: @Smokey_Bud This is by far the best solution to this problem I have seen. Nice!

Comment: This should be the best answer! Thanks

Comment: what parameters need ?, $valueReturn, "tag" , nºtag ¡?¿?¿=

Answer (score 57):

You need to specify the offset for the start of the search as the optional third parameter and calculate it by starting the search directly after the first occurrence by adding the length of what you're searching for to the location you found it at.

```
$pos1 = strpos($haystack, $needle);
$pos2 = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos1 + strlen($needle));
```

Comment: i was going to use preg_match_all. this is much simpler.

Comment: If the length of string which you need to find is just one character. Then you will simply need to add +1 in it.` For example` strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos1 + `1`);

Comment: Adding either `strlen($needle)` or `1` at the end makes a difference for search strings (needles) such as `aa` in subject strings (haystacks) such as `aaaaa`. Is the second occurrence `aa[aa]a` or `a[aa]aa`? That’s probably up to your specific use case.

Answer (score 13):

The recursive function from Smokey_Bud was slowing my script drastically down. Using a regular expression is much faster in this case (for finding any occurence):

```
function strposX($haystack, $needle, $number)
{
    // decode utf8 because of this behaviour: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37391
    preg_match_all("/$needle/", utf8_decode($haystack), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    return $matches[0][$number-1][1];
}

// get position of second 'wide'
$pos = strposX('Hello wide wide world', 'wide', 2);
```

Comment: There is one { too much in this. Besides it seams to work. But I can't tell on the speed.

Comment: Nice solution, but it doesn't account for needles like "(".  I.e., `echo strposX("title (640s) (128x128)", "(", 2)`   <-- that produces a "Compilation failed" error

Answer (score 9):

You can try this, though I haven't tested it out-

```
$pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, strpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle));
```

Comment: This is the best one line solution 

Comment: Could you explain how you did this please :)

Comment: @Coja, 3rd param of strpos is the offset after which position it will look for your target $needle. Here offset is strpos($haystack, $needle)+strlen($needle), which means position of first occurrence of the $needle + length of the $needle.

Answer (score 9):

To find second occurrence of the string you can use the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) along with "offset" parameter, by adding previous offset to strpos.

```
$source = "Hello world, how you doing world...world ?";
$find = "world";
$offset = 0;
$findLength = strlen($find);
$occurrence = 0;

while (($offset = strpos($source, $find, $offset))!== false) {
    if ($occurrence ++) {
      break;
    }
    $offset += $findLength; 
}

echo $offset;
```

You can find all the occurrences by storing offset into an array

```
while (($offset = strpos($source, $find, $offset))!== false) {
  $occurrences[] = $offset;
  $offset += $findLength; 
}
var_export($occurrences);
```

Or can get a specific occurrence by matching $occurrence

```
//find 3rd occurrence
if ($occurrence ++ == 2) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, it's more elegant.

Comment: This does something else (but related), though, and is not really what the question seemed to be about or what a supposed `strposSecond` or `strposX` would do.

Answer (score 3):

Simple is beautiful

```
function strposX($haystack, $needle, $n = 0)
{
    $offset = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);

        if ($pos !== false) {
            $offset = $pos + strlen($needle);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $offset;
}

$offset = strposX($result, "\n", $n);

if ($offset === false) {
    $offset = strlen($result) - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easily, just do it:

```
$i = $pos = 0;    
do {
        $pos = strpos( $string, $needle, $pos+1 );
} while( $i++ < $nth);
```

$nth for your situation is equal to 2.

Comment: This answer is less memory intensive than others answers I have seen here. You may need to adapt Hamze's code slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but how about using `explode`?

```
$corpus = "how many words are there in a dictionary? I'm not going to count them word by word...";
$looking_for = 'word';
$instance = 2;

$parts = explode($looking_for, $corpus, $instance + 1);
array_pop($parts);
$position = strlen(implode($looking_for, $parts));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function strpos_nth( $haystack, $needle, $occurrence ) 
{
    if ( filter_var( $occurrence, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, [ "options" => ["min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>strlen($haystack)] ] ) === false)
        return false ;

    $loop     = 0;
    $position = -1;
    while ( $position!==false && ++$loop<=$occurrence ) 
        $position = strpos( $haystack, $needle, ++$position );

    return $position;
}
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/7d44a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just worked for me to find if are 2 or more occurrence of a char, then by strlen them i found that exist 2 occurrence ex ( i dont use $matches at all):

```
$string = '1234|6|#red';

if(strlen(preg_match_all('/|/', $string,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) ==2){

echo 'i have 2 occurence of char: |';

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if someone's looking for a way to find occurrences from the END of the string (for example 3rd occurrence of dot from the end) the following function works (didn't want to use oncodes function not to mess with encoding)

```
$str = "NooooYesYesNo";

function find_occurence_from_end($haystack, $needle, $num) {

    for ($i=1; $i <=$num ; $i++) {

        # first loop return position of needle
        if($i == 1) {
            $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
        }

        # subsequent loops trim haystack to pos and return needle's new position
        if($i != 1) {

            $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $pos);
            $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);

        }

    }

    return $pos;

}

$pos = find_occurence_from_end($str, "Yes", 2);

// 5
```

It's super simple. Basically each time it finds an occurrence of your needle it "trims" the string to that position. So it keeps on trimming it while returning the latest position each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function substr_Index( $str, $nth ){
    $str2 = '';
    $posTotal = 0;
    for($i=0; $i < $nth; $i++){

        if($str2 != ''){
            $str = $str2;
        }

        $pos   = strpos($str, ':');
        $str2  = substr($str, $pos+1);
        $posTotal += $pos+1;

    }
    return $posTotal-1;
}


echo substr($mystring, substr_Index( $mystring , 2) );
```

Function returns position of nth delimiter.

Second parameter of `substr_Index` must be bigger than 0;

To find second occourance use `substr_Index( $mystring , 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Finds nth occourance of string after position of given needle.
//Pass $needle argument as empty string [''] if you want to find from start
//Pass $needle argument as Int to search string from this position

function substr_Index( $string, $needle, $delimiter, $nth ){
    $str2 = '';
    $posf = strpos($string, $needle);
    if($posf !== false){
        $string   = substr($string, $posf);
        $posTotal = $posf;      
    }else{
        $posTotal = 0;
    }
    
    if( is_int($needle) ){
        $posTotal = $needle;
    }

    for($i=0; $i < $nth; $i++){
        
        if($str2 != ''){
            $string = $str2;
        }
             
        $pos   = strpos($string, $delimiter);
        $str2  = substr($string, $pos + 1);
        $posTotal += $pos+1;
        
    }
    return $posTotal-1;
}
               
//example (returns part of given string from second [:] next from first [#]  )
$str_ = '..:....:..:....#,61185:9789756130346:0000000:369615:97860510:61436=0000000323636';

echo substr($str_, substr_Index( $str_, '#' , ':', 2) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following code ... it works pretty fine for me.

```
<?php
    function f_srch ($s1, $par) {
        echo 'Searching for [' . $par . '] in [' . $s1 . ']<br>';
        $k = 0; //while loop
        $i = 0; // counter

        while ($k >= 0) {
            $pos = strpos($s1, $par, $k);
            if ($pos === false) {
                $k=-1;
                echo 'Letter not found'.'<br>';
            } else {
                if ($pos == $k) { 
                    echo 'The position of the letter is '.$pos.'<br>'; 
                    $i++;
                }
                $k++;
            } 
        }
        echo 'The letter was found ' . $i . ' time(s).'.'<br>'; 
    }
    f_srch('i am searching for a letter in this sentence','t');
?>
```

Answer (score -15):

http://php.net/strpos

```
$newstring = 'abcdef abcdef';
$pos = strpos($newstring, 'a', 1);  // $pos = 7, not 0
```

Comment: That's not quite right because it just starts searching at the second character, so if you had passed in the string `' abcdef abcdef'` with a space at the beginning, it would return `1` rather than `8`, which I think @vfvg was looking for.

Comment: I think we need more thumbs down here