# find the second occurrence of a char in a string php

Tags: php, string

Imagine i have this string :

```
$info="portugal,alemanha,belgica,porto 1-0 alemanha, belgica 2-0";
```

I want to know the position of the 2nd char "-", so i want the result 2-0 and not the result 1-0.

I'm using this function, but it's always returning the first position,

```
$pos = strpos($info, '-');
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126324/question-about-strpos-how-to-get-2nd-occurrence-of-the-string/18589825

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match_all('/-/', $info,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);  
echo $matches[0][1][1];
```

Comment: Try not to answer with just a block of code: add some description of your solution.

Comment: worked, now to understand, you put the regular expression '/-/', so the char '/' represent some char before - and after, right?

What is the meaning of PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE?

and why $matches[0][1][1]

Thank you for the solution

Comment: Old thread, but this is largely unhelpful due to a lack of explanation on how to navigate the data, so I'll provide it:

Firstly, the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag turns the results into an array that captures the position of the found string.

To get the first match, you'd use $matches[0][0], the third match you'd use $matches[0][2], etc.  In this case, $matches[0][1] gets the second match.

That match is (thanks to PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) an array with two values.  $matches[0][1][0] returns just the string that was found ("-").  $matches[0][1][1] returns the position/offset of that string.

Answer (score 26):

Simplest solution for this specific case is to use the [offset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) parameter:

```
$pos = strpos($info, '-', strpos($info, '-') + 1);
```

You might want to look into using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), though.

Comment: shouldn't it be "strpos($info, '-', strpos($info, '-')+1)"?

Comment: just tested, it behaves well even if the string contains zero or just one character. e.g: returns false as expected with no errors.

Comment: For some search strings (`$needle`) you may need `+ strlen($info)` instead of just `+ 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use offset parameter

```
$pos = strpos($info, '-', [offset]);
```

It will work perfectly.

Comment: `offset` specifies the number of characters to skip before looking, not the number of `needle` occurrences to skip