# regex - return part of string when it finds the second occurrence of a character say "$" in php

Tags: php, regex, string

Here i am having a string `"one two $\alpha \beta $ three"`.

What i need is to get the part of string until its second occurrence of a character here it is `"$"` or may be group of characters `"$$"`.

ie, output should be 
`"one two $\alpha \beta $"` and
`"one two $$\alpha \beta $$"` if the string is `"one two $$\alpha \beta $$ three"`.

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492759/find-the-second-occurrence-of-a-char-in-a-string-php

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Couldn't you simply do `.*\$.*\$`? It'll return the strings you want.

Comment: could you please give the code, since i am very new to regex...@ClasG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex `/.*\$.*\$/` will give you what you want.

This code

```
$ptrn='/.*\$.*\$/';
preg_match_all($ptrn, "one two $\alpha \beta $ three", $matches);  
echo $matches[0][0] . "<br>";
preg_match_all($ptrn, "one two $$\alpha \beta $$ three", $matches);  
echo $matches[0][0] . "<br>";
```

will give the following output

```
one two $\alpha \beta $
one two $$\alpha \beta $$
```

So I guess that's what you want. Or...?

Regards

Comment: FYI: this regex is only good for the current string in the original question. In real life, you should avoid `.*` if you need to limit to some number of occurrences. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL1gY2/1).

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `preg_match` function:

```
$str = "one two $\alpha \beta $ three one two $$\alpha \beta $$ three";

preg_match("/[^$]+?[$]{1,2}[^$]+?[$]{1,2}/i", $str, $matches);
// [^$] - matches all symbols excepting '$'
// [$]{1,2} - symbolic class - matches only '$' symbol in quantity from 1 to 2
// ? - supply "ungreedy" matching

var_dump($matches);

// the output:  "one two $\alpha \beta $"
```