# Read more [ only two p tags allowed]

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple blog script for myself and I stucked somewhere.

How can I show only 2 p tags?

i.e

My text:

```
<p>Some text, article here. this is the first paragraph</p>
<p>Some text, article here. this is the second paragraph</p>
<p>Some text, article here. this is the third paragraph</p>
<p>Some text, article here. this is the fourth paragraph</p>
```

How can I make it to return only the first 2 paragraphs?

like this:

```
<p>Some text, article here. this is the first paragraph</p>
<p>Some text, article here. this is the second paragraph</p>
<a href="dont-worry-about-the-link">Read More</a>
```

Comment: Well, where is the text coming from?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126324/question-about-strpos-how-to-get-2nd-occurrence-of-the-string

Comment: @BoltClock it's coming from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fast and dirty** solution. First of it will check it there is more than 2 `</p>` tags. If yes - it will echo only 2 of them + Read more link. Otherwise original string will be printed without link.

```
$aText = explode('</p>', $str);

if (count($aText) > 2)
{
    echo $aText[0].'</p>'.$aText[1].'</p>';
    echo '<a href="">Read more</a>';
}
else
{
    echo $str;
}
```

Comment: $aText = explode('</p>', $str,2); will give exactly two <p> tags.

Comment: Yup, but I assumed that we need to know that there is more than two `</p>` so we can add "read more" link.

Answer (score 0):

give a class name for all the

tags and use jquery as follows:

```
<p class="testClass">Some text, article here. this is the first paragraph</p>
<p class="testClass">Some text, article here. this is the second paragraph</p>
<script>
$(document.ready(function() {
 var count = $('.testClass').length();
 if(count > 2) {
  // append 2 <tags> with readmore link
 }
}))
</script>
```