# Remove everything before 3rd occurance in PHP

Tags: php, substr

i haves string such as

```
andy
**jackie**
rudy
linda
ferry
**jackie**
linda
rudy
ammy
**jackie**
tortia
```

Is it possible to have it removed everything and get the result only below

```
 **jackie**
 tortia
```

it should be possible with substr

thanks

Comment: try using [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) that return Find the position of the LAST occurrence of a substring in a string

Comment: The title says he wants the third occurrence, not the last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use substr. 
But at first you have to find third occurence of jackie. Maybe this function will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/18589825/2701717