# php strpos does not support slashes or symbols?

Tags: php

```
$str = 'https://example.com/tools/onphp.html';

echo strpos($str,'/',0);  //return 6

echo strpos($str,'/',1);  //return 6

echo strpos($str,'/',2);  //return 6

echo strpos($str,'/',3);  //return 6
```

in php 7.3

why is the result returned 6666

i want get result is 'https://www.example.com/' use `substr($str,0,strpos($str,'/',2));`

but it can not working

now i'm use

```
preg_replace('/^([\s\S]*?)\/\/([\s\S]*?)\/([\s\S]*?)$/','\1//\2',$str);
```

so is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: You should look into `parse_url`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: *"why is the result returned 6666"* — Because `strpos` *"[finds] the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string"*. What else did you expect it to do?!

Comment: `https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php`

Comment: The second argument is the character offset, this means from which character it should start looking. I think you are trying to use the second argument as "get the nth encounter of '/'` which is not supported.

Comment: From the manual: `Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

Returns false if the needle was not found.` As such, it always finds the position of the first slash, which just happens to be at index '6'.

Comment: @Angelin Calu  I tried parse_ url，there are other problems when the URL contains ports

Comment: You just need to remember that `PHP_URL_PORT`. I believe that's what you encountered in regards to having ports....

Comment: This is an XY Problem.   You should use a more appropriate tool for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP docs:

```
strpos(string $haystack, mixed $needle, int $offset = 0): int
```

> **offset**: If specified, search will start this number of characters
> counted from the beginning of the string. If the offset is negative,
> the search will start this number of characters counted from the end
> of the string.
>
> **return**: the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (**independent of offset**). Also note
> that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

When you are calling `strpos('https://example.com/tools/onphp.html','/',3)`, the search starts from the character at index 3, which is `'p'`

```
// start - |
strpos('https://example.com/tools/onphp.html', '/', 0); //returns 6
```

If you are trying to find the nth occurence of a string, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126324/question-about-strpos-how-to-get-2nd-occurrence-of-a-string)

Comment: thx ,  i got it , the first time I saw this parameter, I understood it with some deviation